# Using Jasmine, how can I test the returned value of asynchronized call?

Tags: asynchronous, redis, jasmine

I am using jasmine to test the features of redis. As the redis APIs are all asynchronized call, I don't know how to test the result with jasmine `expect().toBe()`. I always see the error:

```
            throw err;
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'expect' of null
```

Here is my test code:

```
var redis = require('redis');

describe("A suite for redis", function() {
    var db = null;

    beforeEach(function() {
        db = redis.createClient();
        // if you'd like to select database 3, instead of 0 (default), call
        // db.select(3, function() { /* ... */ });
        db.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        db.quit();
    });

    it('test string', function(){
        db.set('str_key1', 'hello', redis.print);
        db.get('str_key1', function(err,ret){
            expect(ret).toBe('hello');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For synchronized call, may use Jasmine asynchronous feature, passing a `done()` to `beforeEach()` and `it()`, see:
http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

So, your code can be changed to:

```
var redis = require('redis');

describe("A suite for redis", function() {
    var db = null;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        db = redis.createClient();
        // if you'd like to select database 3, instead of 0 (default), call
        // db.select(3, function() { /* ... */ });
        db.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
        });
        done();
    });

    afterEach(function(done) {
        db.quit();
        done();
    });

    it('test string', function(done){
        db.set('str_key1', 'hello', redis.print);
        db.get('str_key1', function(err,ret){
            expect(ret).toBe('hello');
            done(); // put done() after expect(), or else expect() may report error
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(val).toBe('hello');
```

I don't see "val" is defined in above code, you may want to check "ret".

```
expect(ret).toBe('hello');
```

Comment: thanks for answering. it's a error when i post the code here. but it is not the main reason, as the error seems on expect().